# Activity Disappear when AdView dispaly add`s

Tags: android, admob

I am (first time) using AdMob  com.google.ads.AdView tag in my activity class. The problem is when I open the activity, my text view and image on activity are show for 1,2 seconds after then AdView Display Add`s and my activity TextView and ImageView get Blank. I try to include add in two ways but both are showing Add and disapearing activity.

**AdView Using XML :**

```
                          **activity.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/result_Activity_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/love_result_background" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1s310e4e43247c"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            tools:context=".MyActivity" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/name_Shadow"
                    android:shadowDx="2"
                    android:shadowDy="2"
                    android:shadowRadius="4"
                    android:text="@string/my_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/name_Text"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewFirstNameScore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/score_Shadow"
                    android:text="@string/result"
                    android:textColor="@color/score_Text"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
                                 **activity.java**

// AdMobWidget in onCreate()
        myAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        myAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

**AdView Using Activity :**
I remove `<com.google.ads.AdView  />` from activity.xml in this method

**activity.java**
    *

```
// following code use in onCreate() method
    myAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1s310e4e43247c");

    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.result_Activity_Layout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(480, 75);
    rootView.addView(myAdView, 0, layoutParams);        

    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.UNKNOWN);
    myAdView.loadAd(re);
```

*

Comment: Leo Landau in my question I show both ways for applying AdView. Both are showing adds but after loading activity; text view and image disappear and just Add is showing on the top of screen.

Comment: I'm also having admob intermittantly dissappearing my activity. It's not a crash and the ads do work, it just seems that some ad loads cause the activity to simply vanish.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might be trying to load the ad twice. I would suggest to remove all of the AdView references from java. You don't need to call:

```
myAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
myAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

becuase you have `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` set in XML.

**Another suggestion**:

Try to remove the AdView stuff from both XML and Java to see if the Activity displays properly that way.

Comment: please give me another advice. I already apply this but its not working. Add is displaying and activity other views are disapearing after 1,2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I just include following `android:orientation="vertical"` line in my linear layout and my Add start working. yappiiii .... I got that solution after many hours

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
```

I find out that `android:padding="5dp"` tag should not use in main layout of AdView otherwise it gave following error.  `Not enough space to show ad! Wants: 480, 75, Has: 320, 52`

Leo Landau thanks for your helping :)